# How to use Material Design Lite and Angular for forms

Tags: angularjs, forms, material-design-lite

*Disclaimer: this question is not about using material design in an angular app but using material design ***lite*** inside a form. So, please, don't answer I should rather use angular material, materialize, lumx, material bootstrap, or daemonite... I know, they exist.*

With Angular a typical form field for a name would be:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <label>
  Enter your name:
    <input type="text"
        name="myName"
        ng-model="name"
        ng-minlength="5"
        ng-maxlength="20"
        required />
  </label>
  <div ng-messages="myForm.myName.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
    <div ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
    <div ng-message="maxlength">Your field is too long</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

With Material Design Lite, it would be something like that:

```
<form action="#">
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
     <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="user" pattern="[A-Z,a-z, ]*" />
     <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="user">User name</label>
     <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Letters and spaces only</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Question:** how is it possible to use the angular validation functionality combined with ngMessage (for multiple error messages) with the Material Design Lite?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own angular module to validate MDL input fields, here is a working example: http://codepen.io/alisterlf/pen/ZGgJQB

**JS**

```
  // create angular app
var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', ['fieldMatch']);
//Field Match directive
angular.module('fieldMatch', [])
        .directive('fieldMatch', ["$parse", function($parse) {
                return {
                        require: 'ngModel',
                        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
                                var me = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
                                var matchTo = $parse(attrs.fieldMatch);
                                scope.$watchGroup([me, matchTo], function(newValues, oldValues) {
                                        ctrl.$setValidity('fieldmatch', me(scope) === matchTo(scope));
                                }, true);
                        }
                }
        }]);
//Run material design lite
validationApp.run(function($rootScope, $timeout) {
        $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event) {
                $timeout(function() {
                        componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
                }, 0);
        });
        $rootScope.render = {
                header: true,
                aside: true
        }
});
// create angular controller
validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
        $scope.formStatus = '';
        // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred            
        $scope.submit = function() {
                // check to make sure the form is completely valid
                if ($scope.form.$invalid) {
                        angular.forEach($scope.form.$error, function(field) {
                                angular.forEach(field, function(errorField) {
                                        errorField.$setTouched();
                                })
                        });
                        $scope.formStatus = "Form is invalid.";
                        console.log("Form is invalid.");
                } else {
                        $scope.formStatus = "Form is valid.";
                        console.log("Form is valid.");
                        console.log($scope.data);
                }
        };
});
```